# XMLCiphe.getInstance(String transformation,Cipher cipher) in JAVA 8

Tags: java, security, encryption, java-8

We have been using the following code from XMLCipher.getInstance(String transformation,Cipher cipher) for encryption till now , but it does not work in Java 8 since this method has been removed . Can someone please suggest a possible workaround with JAva 8 . Since I am new to Cipher can I use any other get Instance method for the same.

Comment: XMLCipher is part of an apache library, and not part of the Java 8 SE API. Something else must have happened. Could you add some more information about the problem? The Java upgrade should not be able to cause this.

Comment: @Magnilex Well its reference is from JAva 8 rt.jar

Comment: the package declaration being com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.encryption